# convert T* array (Jet* or float*) to cv::Mat<CV_32f>

Tags: c++, opencv, ceres-solver

I am using ceres-solver with AutoDiffCostFunction. My cost function takes as parameter 1x3 vector and outputs 1x1 residual.
How can I create opencv Mat out of my T* parameter vector? It may be either Jet or float. 
I tried following code, but get error "cannot conver from Jet to float"

```
struct ErrorFunc
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T * const Kparams, T * residual) const // Kparams - [f, u, v]
    {
        cv::Mat K = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_32F);
        K.at<float>(0, 0) = float(Kparams[0]); // error
        K.at<float>(0, 2) = float(Kparams[1]); // error
        K.at<float>(1, 1) = float(Kparams[0]); // error
        K.at<float>(1, 2) = float(Kparams[2]); // error

        Mat Hdot = K.inv() * H * K;

        cv::decomposeHomographyMat(Hdot, K, rot, tr, norm); //want to call this opencv function

        residual[0] = calcResidual(norm);
        return true;
    }
    Mat H;
}
```

There is a way to get Eigen matrix out of T* matrix:

```
const Eigen::Matrix< T, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> hom = Eigen::Map< const Eigen::Matrix< T, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> >(Matrix)
```

but I want to call `cv::decomposeHomographyMat` . How can I do this?

Comment: btw, cv::Mat does not have a [] operator

Comment: Are you able to create a function with this prototype ? float getFromJetAt( Jet* Kparams, int pos ). That function is supposed to get the value in position pos from that Jet. And you don't have to worry about the possibility of it being a float in that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an OpenCV method in a ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction in this way. The OpenCV method is not templated with type T as required by ceres to do the automatic differentiation. The float cast cannot be done because the ceres jet of Jacobians is a vector and not a scalar.

You have two options:

1) Use numerical differentiation: see http://ceres-solver.org/nnls_tutorial.html#numeric-derivatives

2) Use a templated library (e.g. Eigen http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) to rewrite the required homography decomposition